# Refresh Angular JS App again

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application where a part of the page is implemented in angular js. I have a requirement where I have to reload the angular js template coming from the server, based on some user action. I have simulated the exact situation with a dummy code,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  var angApp = angular.module("app", []);

angApp.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
 $scope.p1 = "Hello1";
 $scope.p2 = "Hello2";
})

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});

function add(){
 var tpl = "<div>{{p1}}</div><div>{{p2}}</div>";
 
 $("#container").html("");
 $("#container").html(tpl);
  angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile){
        var obj=$('#angApp');
        var scope = angular.element($("#angApp")).scope();
        $compile(obj.contents())(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    });
  var angControllerScope = angular.element($("#angApp")).scope();
  angControllerScope.$apply(function() {
  angControllerScope.p1 = "New Hello";
 });
}
    </script>

  <body>
 <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <div id="angApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <div id="container">
    <div>{{p1}}</div>
    <div>{{p2}}</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

On click of Add button how to get the value as "Hello" again.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your reasons for wanting to reload actually are, but using JQuery to rewrite the div with the exact same contents won't achieve anything.

Comment: Beyond that, your snippet doesn't demonstrate anything, because the value of the only angular expression you are writing out (`{{p1}}`) never has a different value that needs to be "refreshed".

Comment: thanks claies, I understand it is not the right way, but i have the limitation of the application. Hmm, I believe It should take again the value "Hello" as it is my desired behaviour as controller has value "Hello" attached to it. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: right, It's not that it's not the right way, it's literally that it won't change anything.  And your sample app never sets `p1` to any other value, it is *always* "Hello".  Again, this doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Ok I have added code to refresh value. Ideally it should display "New Hello".

Comment: that doesn't make any sense either.  You can't mix JQuery and angular like that.

Comment: get rid of jQuery and use your data model to drive the angular view. Study some angular tutorials ... mixing jQuery and angular is not the way to do what you are doing

Comment: if you're using jquery inside angular you shouldn't be using angular in the first place. Jack's answer is correct. You need to learn more about angular js and it's template system.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if i have misunderstood what you mean but this is what i think you are trying to achieve...

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.p1 = 'Hello';

  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.p1 = 'New Hello'
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
    <button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    {{p1}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately jack, this is not the way I want. I have a code limitation where I want the code to work the way I have asked. I know this might not make sense, but I am afraid that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had to recompile the template so that the binding with controller again works fine. Below link was useful.

https://gist.github.com/umidjons/1fb8ae674df4c71f85cf

I have updated the initial code with the working version.